# Compare two functions (Checkbox) Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I want to compare this two function

```
const string RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME = "popup_radiobtn01_on";
const string RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME = "popup_radiobtn01_off";
[SerializeField] UIButton livestream = null;
[SerializeField] UIButton render = null;

 public void LiveStreaming()
{

    if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME ;
    } else
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
    }
}

public void Rendering()
{

    if (render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
    } else
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here is that when one checkbox is checked then the other one should not be checked. I'm using the NGUI of Unity by the way and here's an image of what I am trying to do.

Sample image:

[image: imgur.com/a/Zrfsn].

Comment: You may want to check out this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ToggleGroup.html

Comment: @Eldy As I mentioned sir I'm using NGUI

Comment: I don't know NGUI in particular, but I would be surprised if there is not an equivalent of toggle groups.

Comment: Did you read that: http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=6709.0

Comment: @Eldy thanks anyway . Just solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

```
public void LiveStreaming()
{
    //livestream.normalSprite = (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME) ? RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME : RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
    if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        isChecked = true;
        if (isChecked && render.normalSprite == RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    } else
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        isChecked = false;
        if (!isChecked && render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    }
}

public void Rendering()
{
    //render.normalSprite = (render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME) ? RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME : RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
    if (render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        isChecked = true;
        if (isChecked && livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    } else
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        isChecked = false;
        if (!isChecked && livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not perform checks on the name of the UI element sprite.

Comment: @Eldy Why couldn't I??

Comment: You can, but this is bad practice. You should only rely on your `isChecked` boolean, and the sprite should reflect the state of that boolean.